# How to access users table of keycloak h2 database

Tags: database, jboss, keycloak, h2, idp

I have a local keycloak setup. I want to query the users data directly from the keycloak's h2 database. I have opened the keycloak h2 console using the following command

java -cp "C:\Users\kowshiga\Downloads\keycloak-12.0.4\keycloak-12.0.4\modules\system\layers\base\com\h2database\h2\main\h2-1.4.197.jar" org.h2.tools.Console -url "jdbc:h2:C:\Users\kowshiga\Downloads\keycloak-12.0.4\keycloak-12.0.4;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" -user sa -password sa

Using this the h2 cosole opened in browser for me. But I dont find any users table or client table in that console. Now I want to know where the users table is located and how to query the list of users. I have attached the h2 console image in the question. please refer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4fri.png)